# What percentage of people receive SNAP benefits for extended periods of time?

Tags: united-states, social-welfare

The FARRM bills major expenditure, the Supplemental Nutrition Assistance Program (SNAP), supports over 40 million people.

**What percentage of people have received SNAP benefits for more than 5/10/20/30 years?**

(Note: I am interested in cumulative years on SNAP. I believe that there are statistics for average number of months on SNAP before going off it, but do not know if they track people who return to the program.)

Comment: I think dependant is the wrong word here.  Perhaps change it to reliant.

Comment: In addition to @Chad's thought, I'm not sure comparisons to animals are appropriate.

Comment: I also think that it is not a statistic that is maintained to how many times a person has received SNAP Aid in their lifetime.  I believe,  only information they maintain is about the most recent time where SNAP Aid was applied for.  I believe this because I have knowledge of a sister program and this is how the legislation directed us to maintain the history.  It is possible SNAP is run differently but both programs are Ag programs so I doubt it

Comment: Interesting reference, although it doesn't directly address your question: http://www.trivisonno.com/food-stamps-charts

Comment: @Chad, doesn't reliant and dependent mean the same thing? In what way do they differ?

Comment: Dependant = can not exist without, Reliant = Relies on them but could potentially find another source. (this is an ugly defintion but basically accurate)

Comment: @Chad, Ok, I don't see a difference.. [reliant](http://www.freedictionary.com/reliant), adj. "Having or exhibiting reliance; dependent."

Comment: @Bobson, it is a biological truism that humns are animals. This question is looking for evidence that biological truth of feeding animals leds to their dependence is either true/false in the homosapian species. Why the downvotes?

Comment: You can be reliant and not dependant.  But you cannot be dependent but not reliant.  I rely on my medical coverage to pay my medical bills.  But If they do not pay them I could also pay them myself, and then spend fun hours on hold trying to figure out why they choose not to cover the charges.

Comment: @Chad, what is your definition for "reliant" (source). and what do you think reliant means. From the differences you describe above, it seems that 'dependent' is the right term. Park rangers don't want you to feed the animals, because the animals will be dependent on humans feeding them to survive. That is the same question, but with SNAP instead. (I suppose you could be claiming that people on SNAP don't need it to survive, if so then that seems like a good reason to cut the program. All this Republcans want to starve   millions of people argument is bunk, then?

Comment: @user1873 - They're synonyms (same denotation), but they have different connotations.  Consider the difference between `unrelenting` and `mulish`.  Both are synonyms for `stubborn`, but they imply very different things.  That being said, connotations are much more variable than definitions.

Comment: Humans are more adaptable than animals.  I also think there is some overblown hyperbole in the ranger claims.  The animals learn they can get high calorie food from humans and so they become pests because the reward for being a pest is high calorie food.  So they make poor choices... but if their are no humans around they scrounge.

Comment: **Lets move the reliant/dependent debate over to [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141600/difference-in-usage-between-dependent-and-reliant).**

Comment: @Chad, wow more simlarities with the animal world. humans learn that they can receive free food (and other benefits) and become pests. They make poor choices as long as humans are around for them to receive benefits from.

Comment: @user1873 - Hmm maybe they should put humans in the animal kingdom.

Comment: @Chad, I thought that [humans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human) were? Is **regina dolus** a seperate species?

Comment: My point is that your wording assumes that these people do not have a choice or alternative.  This is not the case.  The system rewards them for staying in a state where they are not able to provide for themselves, that is different from putting them in a position where they are unable to choose to do otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

**Note: This *does not* directly answer the question, but can serve as a starting point for the research,** which is why I'm leaving it here for now.  The numbers being asked for may not have ever been gathered and analyzed, but if they have, they don't seem to be in the linked-to study.

---

I found a [summary](http://myfoodstamps.org/pdf_files/Lengthbenefits06.pdf) of a [2006 report](http://naldc.nal.usda.gov/download/32801/PDF) on how long SNAP participants receive benefits, which has a chart which somewhat your question for August 1990 - October 1999.

I haven't been able to track down a more recent study, but for that decade only 21% of the people stayed on for more than two years after joining the program.  From the report:

> Among all individuals participating in March 1996, SIPP data suggest that half were in the middle of participation spells lasting four and a half years or longer, while FSPQC data indicate that only one-third of the caseload was in the middle of spells of at least four and a half years. In FSPQC data, the median participation spell for March 1996 participants was just over two years. While it is unclear why the estimates from these separate sources differ, it appears that the estimated median participation spell of eight years for a cross-section of FSP participants is no longer an accurate depiction of the FSP dynamics.

Comment: If you examine my Note above, this isn't the information i am looking for. "participation spell" sounds like continuious years in the program. I am interested in cumulative years, while your data is only people who never dropped out of the program.

Comment: @user1873 - You're right.  I strongly suspect they don't track re-entries, but I'll see if I can track anything down for that.  However, wouldn't the very fact that they went off it for a period of time indicate that they could get by without the program and are thus not dependent on it?

Comment: @bobson - *wouldn't the very fact that they went off it for a period of time indicate that they could get by without the program and are thus not dependent on it* yes except for the fact that the way the program works based on the income of the person who applies more foodstamps could be issued.  If you apply you have to provide proof of your(and your spouses if you have one(though not your baby daddy's)) income, but you do not have to provide proof of income for other members of your household.  So it may be benficial to let your sister claim you as a dependant to get more FS.

Comment: The above is an exploit of the system but it is a known and commonly used exploit.  In that scenrio they are never not reliant on the Food stamps.

Comment: @Chad - Interesting.  I wouldn't have even considered that.  And it definitely would demonstrate what user1873's looking for.  However, I'd be really surprised if there were actually numbers for that if the government isn't tracking it (as implied by being able to do that in the first place).

Comment: @Bobson - the actual losses to the gaming of the system are tiny compared to the size of the program, and there is no political points in targeting the people using the exploit.  And if the people step out of line they can yank their foodstamps and welfare.  It is a tool of terrorism on the underclass in the US.